# Как сделать чтоб тело, голова и руки вели себя как макароны?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно чтоб тело, руки и голова вели себя как макароны и сваливая тело и конечности персонажа влево или вправо.Как в human fall flat, В Unity 3d

Comment: Сделай сначала ноги твердыми, а потом уже можешь переходить к макаронам

Comment: @Вини Слушай, я тут посмотрел у тебя в профиле - у тебя куча заданных вопросов и ни один без проставленной "галочки" на ответе который тебе помог. Тебе что, ответы не помогают? А то некрасиво как-то выходит, это уже не первый вопрос на который я тебе отвечаю.

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, надо поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2):

[т.к. заголовок противоречит вопросу решил ответить на заголовок]
("конечности" в заголовке и "тело" в вопросе)

Наверняка это делается через Joint-ы. Ты делаешь ими 4-5-6 соединений на руках и они во время ФИЗИЧЕСКОГО передвижения должны будут двигаться как сваренное спагетти под действием физического движка.

Comment: Andrew, вот чувствуется - реально крутой! я смотрел на вопрос, как баран на новые ворота, и даже не знал, как к такому подступиться. А весть ответ - такой простой!

Comment: @S.H., дело не в том, что ответ простой, а в том, что он скорее всего* не поможет. Если автор не способен нагуглить информации о joint, что очень просто, то нагуглить иформацию о том как ими пользоваться (их много видов) он вряд ли* сможет.   * - мат. погрешность в рамках приличия.

Comment: @Yaroslav я в свое время не знал о сериализации. Как я не гуглил - ничего  толкового не находил. Поэтому когда мне ответили на SO словом "сериализация" - я нашел все что нужно) Иногда одно слово решает) Будем надеятся что это такой же случай.

Comment: @Andrew, все с чего-то начинали, сам писал god классы по 2к строк. Мой первый вопрос на стеке был, о том как делать триангуляцию и это были не 2 строчки, а текст с картинкой. Не знал как это называется и самого слова мне оказалось достаточно, хотя ответов было много и люди даже начали спорить, какой метод лучше подойдёт и вроде даже пост закрыли из-за того что "невозможно дать объективный ответ" (ненавижу этот пункт ). В надежду не верю  если вижу что человек пытается, пускай код говно, но свой, есть с чем работать, а вот вопрос состоящий по сути из названия поста... ну нет.

Comment: Но чудеса на стеке всё-же случаются  Когда в хреналионный раз выложили код 2д платформера из интернета (один и то-же), который выкладывали +/- раз в месяц, а то и два и я хейтил по этому поводу, после чего получил бан, уже как год я этот код не видел. Прям вот не обидно после этого было в бане посидеть . Правда это чудо скорее связано падением рейтинга стека .

Comment: @Yaroslav Вероятнее всего чудо стало в том, что видео с бесящим тебя кодом опустилось в поисковой ранжировке)

Comment: Меня в какой-то момент бомбило от изобилия вопросов полными нулями в юнити.... Какой-то дикий период был - кучи вопросов и буквально полностью все от нулевих по знанию. Даж вопрос на мете создал что мож ограничить как-то.... Или хотя бы в описании написать предупреждение о том что лучше освоить базу, а потом лезть в юнити.... Но захейтили... Но при этом тоже после этого каким-то чудом подобных вопросов стало значительно меньше.

Comment: @Andrew, ага . Интересно что-же его заменило.

Comment: @Andrew, я ток понимаю, всё волнами и это была до меня ~в периуд выхода IPhone-5 во время бума инди игр на unity. Я тогда сидел на obj-c cocos2d .